# PHP Session: Preset login details only working locally

Tags: php, html

I am working on a website and I decided to make my own CMS for it. It doesn't need amazing security but I do have a login page for it that directs to the CMS page if the login information is correctly filled out.

It's only possible to login with 1 account (admin). And its login name and password are set within the login page PHP file. When submitting the form it checks if the right information is filled out, and if so, it puts the username within a SESSION[user] variable.

Aslong as that session exists the loginpage should always autodirect you to the CMS page, but this only seems to work locally. When i put it online, and fill out the right information and submit the form on the loginpage, it just stays on the same page instead of going to the CMS page. When i manually type in the URL of the cms page I can access it without being directed to the loginpage. And in my PHP i do check whether $_SESSION['user'] == admin.

Any of you guys have an idea why this only works locally, and what I need to change to make it work online too?

Here is the relevant code:

//LOGIN PHP PAGE

```
<?php
session_start();
    //login info
    $xinlognaam = 'admin';
    $xwachtwoord = 'PASSWORD HERE';

    //als je al ingelogd bent, wordt je direct naar cms pagina gestuurd
    if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])){
        if($_SESSION['user'] == $xinlognaam){
            header("Location: ../php/cms.php");
        }
    }
?>

    <div id="inlogsectie">
        <form id="inlogform" method="POST" action="#">

            Accountnaam:<br><br>
            <input type="text" name="accountnaam" id="accountnaam" maxlength="100"/><br><br><br>

            Wachtwoord:<br><br>
            <input type="text" name="wachtwoord" id="wachtwoord" maxlength="100"/><br><br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="inlogknop" id="inlogknop" value="inloggen"/>
        </form>

        <div id="inlogmelding">
            <?php
                //als op de knop gedrukt wordt
                if(isset($_POST['inlogknop'])){
                    //als velden niet leeg zijn
                    if(!empty($_POST['accountnaam']) && !empty($_POST['wachtwoord'])) {
                        //als de gegevens correct zijn
                        if(($xinlognaam == $_POST['accountnaam']) && ($xwachtwoord == $_POST['wachtwoord'])){
                            $_SESSION['user'] = $xinlognaam;
                            header("Location: ../php/cms.php");
                        //als de gegevens incorrect zijn
                        }else{
                            echo"De ingevulde login informatie is incorrect.";
                        }
                    } else{ //als velden leeg zijn
                        echo"De ingevulde login informatie is incorrect.";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

//CMS PAGE

```
 <?php
  session_start();

 if($_SESSION['user'] != 'admin'){
        header('Location: ../admin/index.php');
    }

 if(isset($_POST['uitlogknop'])){
        include_once('uitloggen.php');
    }
   ?>
```

//LOG OUT PHP FILE

```
<?php
session_destroy();

header("Location: ../admin/index.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot set the `header()` after content has been sent to the browser. So your login page will have issues. I would suggest:

```
<?php
session_start();
//login info
$xinlognaam = 'admin';
$xwachtwoord = 'knipwerk';
$html = "";

//als je al ingelogd bent, wordt je direct naar cms pagina gestuurd
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    if($_SESSION['user'] == $xinlognaam){
       header("Location: ../php/cms.php");
    }
}

//als op de knop gedrukt wordt
if(isset($_POST['inlogknop'])){
    //als velden niet leeg zijn
    if(!empty($_POST['accountnaam']) && !empty($_POST['wachtwoord'])) {
        //als de gegevens correct zijn
        if(($xinlognaam == $_POST['accountnaam']) && ($xwachtwoord == $_POST['wachtwoord'])){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $xinlognaam;
            header("Location: ../php/cms.php");
            //als de gegevens incorrect zijn
        } else {
            $html .= "De ingevulde login informatie is incorrect.";
        }
    } else {
        //als velden leeg zijn
        $html .= "De ingevulde login informatie is incorrect.";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<div id="inlogsectie">
    <form id="inlogform" method="POST" action="#">
        <p><label>Accountnaam:</label>
        <input type="text" name="accountnaam" id="accountnaam" maxlength="100"/></p>
        <p><label>Wachtwoord:</label>
        <input type="text" name="wachtwoord" id="wachtwoord" maxlength="100"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="inlogknop" id="inlogknop" value="inloggen" /></p>
    </form>
    <div id="inlogmelding">
    <?php echo $html; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. Since the php code comes right before a `<div>` i asume there is a `<html>`, a `<head>` and a `<body>` tag somewhere above that would mess it up.

Comment: Possibly, but I do not make assumptions. Only OP can tell us.

Comment: Yep there is a HTML tag above it, but I managed to just put the header parts above that as well. However, when I closed a php tag and put another php header (of the loginform validation) between a 2nd pair of php tags beneath it, this didn't properly work. So now all the PHP code that includes headers at the very top of my file, between one pair of PHP tags. And it works just how I wanted it now :) Thanks guys! @Twisty

Comment: You cannot write multiple separate `header()` lines to a page. Headers must be presented before the HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

The `header()` function that you use for the redirect does only work if no content has been sent yet. After content has been sent, the HTTP-header can not be modified as it has already been sent from the server to the client.

That means that if you put the call to `header()` after any HTML (even if it is just a `<html>` tag or a single `echo` or even a space before the opening `<?php`) it might not work. I say might, because sometimes the server does not sent all the content the second it is generated, and therefore it might still be possible to edit the HTTP-header.

So the solution is to move the `header()` call to the very top of the page. More info can be found in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Also, don't post your password to Stack Overflow. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your problem:

```
> <?php session_start() ?>
> 
> <?php 
> 
> 
> if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {  header('Location:
> ../php/cms.php'); } else {
> 
> ?>    <div id="inlogsectie">
>         <form id="inlogform" method="POST" action="">
> 
>             Accountnaam:<br><br>
>             <input type="text" name="accountnaam" id="accountnaam" maxlength="100"/><br><br><br>
> 
>             Wachtwoord:<br><br>
>             <input type="text" name="wachtwoord" id="wachtwoord" maxlength="100"/><br><br><br>
> 
>             <input type="submit" name="inlogknop" id="inlogknop" value="inloggen"/>
>         </form> <?php  }  if(isset($_POST['inlogknop'])) {
>               if(!empty($_POST['accountnaam']) && !empty($_POST['wachtwoord'])){
>                       if(($xinlognaam == $_POST['accountnaam']) && ($xwachtwoord == $_POST['wachtwoord'])){
>               
>               $_SESSION['user'] = $xinlognaam;
>                 header('Location: ../php/cms.php');           } else {
>           
>               echo"De ingevulde login informatie is incorrect.";
>                           }
>                   }else {
>                       echo"De ingevulde login informatie is incorrect.";      }   }    ?>
```